Is gravitational potential energy of body by $mgh$ negative?
Potential energy is found by two formulas:
$P.E=mgh$ (in earth, at acceleration g)
$P.E=-Gm1m2/r^2 * h  \approx -Gm1m2/r$
I am not worried about the approximation of h=r, or use of g in earth, My question is about the use of different sign for potential energy
Eg:
Consider a 15kg object at 1m from earth ground level,
is P.E = 15kg * 9.8m/s^2 * 1m = 147J
or P.E = -Gm1m2/r^2 * h = -9.8 * 15kg * 1m= -147J
Question: After browsing for a while on debate of potential energy's sign, I learnt it to be negative and feel -147J is correct ,if so does that mean that using mgh with g as +9.8 we are finding the magnitude of P.E?

Edit: I used values only to make my question clear, and it was neither my h.w, nor check my work. I meant only to ask about underlying physics reason.

Your first expression makes an assumption that the Earth's ground level has PE=0 whereas your second expression is so inconsistent that there is no way to help fix it.

Voting to reopen. Just because a question contains defined variables and a numerical example does not automatically make it a homework question. The OP wants to know if gravitational potential energy is a positive or negative quantity and if the mgh equation is fundamentally physically different from the $GMm/R$ formulation. That is not homework or check my working. It is perfectly acceptable to ask what the physical meaning of an equation is.

The key here is that it is the difference in potential energy that is important and this yields the same result in magnitude and sign, using either equation.
The potential energy is obtained by integrating the force of gravity by the distance moved to obtain the energy in terms of work done:
\begin{aligned}
\text{PE} &= \int\limits^{r_2}_{r_1} \frac{GMm}{R^2} \mathrm{d}R \\
&= -\frac{GMm}{R_2} -(-)\frac{GMm}{R_1}.
\end{aligned}
Conventionally we choose the baseline $R_1$ to be infinity, so that the potential energy goes to zero in the limit that the radius goes towards infinity so that:
$$\text{PE} = -\frac{GMm}{R},$$
where the negative sign just falls out from taking the integral.
At the surface of the Earth (radius = $6371 \ \text{km}$ or $6371000 \ \text{m}$) the potential energy is:
$$\text{PE}_0 = -\frac{GMm}{R} = \frac{GM\times 15}{6371000} = -936537000 \ \text{Joules}.$$
One meter above the surface of the Earth ($R = 6371000+1 \ \text{m}$) the potential energy is:
$$\text{PE}_1 = -\frac{GMm}{R} = \frac{GM\times 15}{6371001} \approx -936536853 \text{ Joules}.$$
The difference in potential energy is $$\text{PE}_1 - \text{PE}_0 = -936536853 - (-) \ 936537000 \ \text{Joules} = + 147 \ \text{Joules}.$$
Notice that the sign of the potential energy difference is positive and the same in both magnitude and sign to the potential difference calculated using the $mgh$ formula.
The $mgh$ formula uses ground level as the baseline. While the two formulas use different baselines, the potential energy at a greater height is always greater using either formula. Using the  $\dfrac{GMm}{R}$ formula, the potential energy increase from $-936537000 \ \text{Joules}$ to $-936536853 \ \text{Joules}$ one meter higher up. Using the $mgh$ formula, the potential energy increases from $0 \ \text{Joules}$ at ground level to $+ 147 \ \text{Joules}$ one meter higher up.
When an object of mass $m= 15 \ \text{kg}$, falls from a height $h=1 \ \text{m}$, its kinetic energy increases by $147 \ \text{Joules}$ and its potential energy decrease by the same amount whichever formula you use for potential energy. However, it should be noted that the $mgh$ formula is only an approximation and is only valid for short distances, where the acceleration of gravity is considered to be constant.

Thanks! was looking for such in depth reason. btw, in integration R^2 will be R in denominator right,after taking displacement $h \approx  R$

Yes, the force equation is proportional to $R^{(-2)}$ and after the integration with respect to R, the result is proportional to $ -R^{(-1)}$.

oh yeah, thanks

The two expressions have different locations for their energy zero points, that is why they disagree.
$mgh$ is zero at wherever you have set $h=0$ to be with your coordinate system. Typically that is "ground level" in the context of the calculation.
$-G m_1 m_2 / r$ is only zero when $m_1$ and $m_2$ are infinitely far away from eachother.

It is worse than that. Yes, the $r=\infty$ is the necessary zeroing point for the usual standard GPE formula, but this one is using forces, and that does not require that particular zeroing point. So, in a sense, the $h$ value appearing in his formula thus means that he picked ground level $+h$ as the zeroing point, a particularly awkward place.

Sure, I did not bother correcting that erroneous formula but I probably should have...

Gravitation potential energy can have any sign you want:
$$ U(h) = mgh + C $$
since you can add any constant $C$.
Down is the direction of decreasing $U$, though, as the $m$ becomes more tightly bound to the source of the gravitation the lower it is. This is, for example, why you need to expend energy to put a satellite into orbit.

You can't just add any C because of E=mc2

this comment makes no sense.

@Alienfromfuture the potential energy does not directly contribute to mass-energy; kinetic energy and mass energy do, but potential energy is not the same and is invariant under arbitrary additions/subtractions to the potential

This comment makes no sense. KE and mass energy contribute to mass-energy. Is mass energy and mass-energy different thing?
